# LinguaPlone Not Translating Home Page by default

Tags: plone, linguaplone

I have Plone 4.0.2 setup with LinguaPlone 4.0.1 and all of my pages (including "Home", "About", "Contact", etc.) translated into French and Spanish (English as default).  I get the three languages available in the top-right corner of the screen and when I click on any other language, the site and all page contents are translated properly (including the navigation tabs, so "Home" becomes "Accueil" in French, and "Inicio" in Spanish).

The problem is when I am browsing the site as a different language and click on "Home" (or "Accueil"/"Inicio"), the home page displays in English.  Yet everything else is still in that other language (French/Spanish).  I have to re-click the language I want to view the homepage as before it is displayed in that language.

The home page is the only page that this doesn't work on.  I can navigate to any other part of the site in French or Spanish and everything but the Home page displays properly.  Is there some strange setting I'm missing for the home/default page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add translations to a Plone site front-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905349/how-can-i-add-translations-to-a-plone-site-front-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer on [How can I add translations to a Plone site front-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905349/how-can-i-add-translations-to-a-plone-site-front-page); you need to run the LinguaPlone setup:

```
http://localhost:8080/Plone/@@language-setup-folders
```

Comment: I ran this setup and it didn't help.  I get to my home page and click "Translate into..." and Click on "Spanish".  It takes me to the side-by-side editor and I make my changes.  However, when ever I click on "Inicio", it still displays the English translation of my home page (even though there is a Spanish translation saved), and if I click on "Contenidos" (contents) it has my translated page listed there.  Under "Display" the item selected is the English version of the home page, and if i change the content item as default, it only lists the English version...

Comment: Sounds like your setup isn't complete; when you click on "Home", what does your URL look like? Does it still have the language folder in the path?

Comment: No it does not - it just has the normal URL.  I assume this is where it is messing up?

Comment: Looks like the default view for the site root wasn't set up; it should be "language-switcher" (see [the setup source](https://github.com/plone/Products.LinguaPlone/blob/master/Products/LinguaPlone/browser/setup.py#L104). Find the "Portal Site" type in your ZMI types tool and make sure it's default view is configured properly ('language-switcher' listed in view methods, default view set to 'language-switcher'). Also, we should probably switch to SO chat or to #plone IRC on freenode.net.

Comment: The project I was working on had been delayed quite a bit (waiting for a time where we could upgrade Plone).  After the upgrade (for both Plone and LinguaPlone) I followed your instructions and everything appears to be working properly!